# Why is Studio not importing some parts of LEGO Mindstorms EV3?

Tags: bricklink-studio

I was trying to import the LEGO Mindstorms EV3 31313 set into Studio when I got this error :
[image: Error that I got when importing LEGO Mindstorms EV3 31313 set into Studio]
It says that some parts, including the most important ones like the EV3 Brick, the motors and sensors, failed to import. I am new to Studio, so it would be great if anyone could help me with this issue.

Comment: Tried this, the motor components give warnings because the reported color is black (should be N/A) and the fairings give errors because they are stickered. Don't think there is much you can do about this except file a bug report with stud.io ...